# Please add the directory containing “/Users/me/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm, textmate2

I am trying to my ruby code in TextMate and I am planning to use a specific gem with a bundle I have. When I try to run my ruby code with command + R, I get the following error.

What is wrong with my path?

The current PATH is:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/me/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin
/Users/me/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby

Please add the directory containing “/Users/me/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby
/Users/me/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby” to PATH in TextMate's Shell Variables preferences.
```

However, as you can see, `/Users/me/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby` is added.

If I add just directory, not the rvm-auto-ruby file

The current PATH is:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/me/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin
/Users/me/.rvm/bin

Please add the directory containing “/Users/me/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby” to PATH in TextMate's Shell Variables preferences.
```

I get same error.

SOLUTION: (needed to change the order)

/Users/me/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 1):

Set your path to include:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/bin
```

Not:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby
```

The former is the path to the directory containing the executable. The latter is the complete path to the binary. Your $PATH should include directories, not files.

Comment: I tried it, but it points to the wrong ruby, and wrong gem.path

Comment: Then it sounds like you have a separate question unrelated to your original question. Did the change I recommend fix the _Please add the directory containing ..._ error message you asked about?

Comment: No, it did not fix the issue. Same error, with the directory only